# Laravel PHP - Prepend Timestamp to Artisan Console Output

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am using the Laravel PHP framework.

What is the best way to prepend a timestamp to the Artisan console output (ie. `$this->info`, `$this->error`) for the `App\Console\Command` class?

I don't want to have to repeat a timestamp method in each and every line. I'd rather have it be automatic.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to do it (assuming you're on Laravel 5.0+):

PrependsOutput.php

```php
<?php 

namespace App\Console\Commands;

trait PrependsOutput
{
    public function line($string)
    {
        parent::line($this->prepend($string));
    }

    public function comment($string)
    {
        parent::comment($this->prepend($string));
    }

    public function error($string)
    {
        parent::error($this->prepend($string));
    }

    public function info($string)
    {
        parent::info($this->prepend($string));
    }

    public function warn($string)
    {
        parent::warn($this->prepend($string));
    }

    protected function prepend($string)
    {
        if (method_exists($this, 'getPrependString')) {
            return $this->getPrependString($string).$string;
        }

        return $string;
    }
}
```

PrependsTimestamp.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

trait PrependsTimestamp
{
    protected function getPrependString($string)
    {
        return date(property_exists($this, 'outputTimestampFormat') ?
            $this->outputTimestampFormat : '[Y-m-d H:i:s]').' ';
    }
}
```

Then in your command:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class MyCommand extends Command
{
    use PrependsOutput, PrependsTimestamp;

    protected $signature = 'mycommand';
    protected $description = '';

    // you can override the default format
    // protected $outputTimestampFormat = '(m/d/Y H:i:s)';

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->comment('comment');
        $this->info('info');
        $this->warn('warn');
        $this->error('error');
        $this->line('line');
    }
}
```

Outcome:

[image]

Comment: Not sure if it's a Laravel 5.5 thing, but now you only need to override the `line()` method and that takes care of all of the output methods.

Comment: Should also pass through the `$style` and `$verbosity` parameters e.g. 
`public function line($string, $style = NULL, $verbosity = NULL)`

Comment: With Laravel 5.8 its now as simple as overriding `line($string, $style = NULL, $verbosity = NULL)` as @aaron already pointed out.

Answer (score 10):

From laravel 5.5 you can just add this trait.

and use it in your Console Commands

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

trait PrependsTimestamp
{
    public function line($string, $style = null, $verbosity = null)
    {
        $timestamped = date('[Y-m-d H:i:s] ') . ucfirst($style) . ': ' . $string;

        $styled = $style ? "<$style>$timestamped</$style>" : $timestamped;

        $this->output->writeln($styled, $this->parseVerbosity($verbosity));
    }
}
```

**Same Output:**

[image]

Comment: Elegantly what I need, working in Laravel 8+

Answer (score 2):

[@peterm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1920232/peterm)'s answer adjusted for Laravel 5.8 (and maybe earlier):

- Needs to adhere to parents method signature for `line()`.
- overriding `line()` is enough to prepend text for all output types

PrependsOutput.php

```php
<?php 

namespace App\Console\Commands;

trait PrependsOutput
{
    public function line($string, $style = null, $verbosity = null)
    {
        parent::line($this->prepend($string), $style, $verbosity);
    }

    protected function prepend($string)
    {
        if (method_exists($this, 'getPrependString')) {
            return $this->getPrependString($string) . $string;
        }

        return $string;
    }
}
```

PrependsTimestamp.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

trait PrependsTimestamp
{
    protected function getPrependString($string)
    {
        return date(property_exists($this, 'outputTimestampFormat') ?
            $this->outputTimestampFormat : '[Y-m-d H:i:s]').' ';
    }
}
```

Then in your command:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class MyCommand extends Command
{
    use PrependsOutput, PrependsTimestamp;

    protected $signature = 'mycommand';
    protected $description = '';

    // you can override the default format
    // protected $outputTimestampFormat = '(m/d/Y H:i:s)';

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->comment('comment');
        $this->info('info');
        $this->warn('warn');
        $this->error('error');
        $this->line('line');
    }
}
```

Outcome:

[image]